# UDP Hole-punching: cannot send from server to client

Tags: rust, udp, nat

Starting with server-A (globally reachable via static IP), I bind a UDP socket to 0.0.0.0:25000.

Then with client-A behind a (residential) NAT, I bind a UDP socket to 0.0.0.0:25000. Client-A then sends a packet to server-A.

Server-A receives the packet. Server-A records the remote socket, K, from where the packet was NAT'ed. Server-A sends a packet to K with the intention that the NAT forward the packet to client-A.

However, client-A does not receive the packet. On the NAT, when I enable port triggering on port 25000 for UDP, then it works. However, in the making of a p2p app, I'd prefer to stay away from requiring clients to go into the router settings to make the program work. How can I punch a hole through the firewall such that the communication is bidirectional?

Answer (score 0):

If your router/NAT device supports NAT-PMP or UPNP, then it is really easy. You just need to realise the protocol and open the specific port for use. If not, then you may need to use ICE.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late, but use nat hole punching. You could do that with tools like pwnat. There is a really good description how it works on the gh-page.https://github.com/samyk/pwnat . It is quite easy to grasp and if you are experienced enough maybe you can code it in rust.